# How do I expand my VD on LSI 9361-16i?

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, lsi, raid6, storcli

I've got a 9361-16I installed in a supermicro sc847. I have the 2 expanders running in a cascaded configuration with both of them chaining off port 0-4 of the card. They are being exposed as enclosure 30 and 31. [Array Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoKsH.jpg)

I have 24 Shucked Easystore drives in the front 24 slots running Raid6 for a total of 160TB. I just put 3 newly shucked drives in the back slots and wanted to expand my array onto them as well. I've had absolutely no problems doing this on the front side of the chassis. Array Info
When I try to expand (migrate) the array, I get error code 13 Disk doesn't have enough capacity.[Failed Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGIwr.jpg)

What I don't understand is why the controller thinks they are a different size because as far as I can tell they are exactly the same [Drive E30:S2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4S4G.png) [Drive E31:S2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXORG.png)

Any help would be appreciated!